# What is common pratice to restrict request to Restful API Server?

Tags: rest, authentication, http-headers

I know there is CORS rule for restricting cross origin resource requests, but somehow that's only work on browser. The REST server still vulnerable to foreign/unknown request like from CURL or any DDoS tools, but I still want the server can be tested with tool like Postman or benchmark tools only from my computer for example.

Restricting by IP also doesn't work because IP addresses can be mocked and it always changes. So probably the best approach should be using Authorization header. But here's the problem.

Let say i have 3 entities involved for this setup:

1. User Browser

   For logged in users, it stores authentication token `XYZ_TOKEN` for determining what capabilities of this user can do to the frontend and the backend server.
2. Frontend Server

   Will receive/checks the `XYZ_TOKEN` stored inside session storage of the browser. Also it has API KEY `XYZ_API_KEY` that needed for every request sent to the backend server
3. Backend Server

   Will receive two authorization headers. The API KEY (mandatory) and the User Token (optional). The API KEY will be checked inside the web server (nginx/apache) and the user token will be checked inside the application, because it determines the role, user, and capabilites for that user.

Can we send two authorization header at the same time? E.g.

```bash
request headers: Authorization: bearer "XYZ_API_KEY" Authorization: bearer "XYZ_TOKEN"
```

Or there is another better approach to achieve this?